# How can I download part of a playlist from YouTube with 'youtube-dl'?

Tags: youtube, youtube-dl

I have been using

```
youtube-dl -c -f 'bestvideo[height<=720]+bestaudio/best[height<=720]' https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLgsYTUetbpwNRmhee8yc_4o4MTY_naAmO
```

to download a playlist from YouTube, but I was wondering if there is a way I can, for example, download videos 2 through 8 (out of a playlist of 10 for example) or the first 5 videos or the last 6 videos or even from video 7 onward?

Is there a way this can be done using `youtube-dl`?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can use: `--playlist-start`, `--playlist-end`, `--playlist-reverse` or `--playlist-items` to achieve this goal.

For example to download 2 through 8:

```
youtube-dl -c -f '...' --playlist-start 2 --playlist-end 8 https://youtube.com/watch/foo
```

To download first 5:

```
youtube-dl -c -f '...' --playlist-end 5 https://youtube.com/watch/foo
```

From 7 onward:

```
youtube-dl -c -f '...' --playlist-start 7 https://youtube.com/watch/foo
```

Or to download 2,4,6:

```
youtube-dl -c -f '...' --playlist-items 2,4,6 https://youtube.com/watch/bar
```

Or even specify a  range of videos:

```
youtube-dl -c --playlist-items 2-3,5,8-10,18 https://youtube.com/watch/bar
```

---

To get the last ones you should use `--playlist-reverse`, for example for last 6:

```
youtube-dl -c -f '...' --playlist-end 6 --playlist-reverse
```

Comment: thanks for the help. this is great. Just another question... Say I'm downloading from a batch file, and in that batch file there is a link to a playlist, is something like what you mentioned above possible in this scenario?

Comment: @natral I'm not sure about it... I have to test and see what happens :)